# Backup Exec 2014 Insert Over writable Media into the robotic library

Tags: backup, ibm, backupexec, symantec

We have Backup exec 2014 along with IBM TS3100 Tape Library.  I have made partitions defined (one for each day of the week) and all of my jobs run fine.  From few weeks we are getting 'Inset overwriteable media into the robotic library' errors very frequently. In JOB settings, I am using "Overwrite media" when this job begins.

We thought it might be dueto tapes, we inserted new un-used tapes but still getting error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1:

Run a Import Job on the media/slot to change the "Export Pending" state to "No" to allow the media to be written to for a backup job. 
If the media still shows up as "Export Pending Yes" after running the import job as mentioned in step 1 then perform steps mentioned in step 2.

### Step 2:

Make a copy of Backup Exec catalogs folder (Just in case the changes needs to be rolled back).

---

**Note**: The default location of catalog folder for Backup Exec for Windows Servers 11d and above is the C:\Program Files\Symantec\Backup Exec\Catalogs.
Move the media which is in the state of "Export Pending Yes" to retired media set and then delete it.
Re-inventory the slot containing the media.  Now the export pending on that slot should show as 'No' and the media should be usable again

Source https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.000033762